# SELECT FROM a subquery table consisting of a TRANSFORM ... PIVOT table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following functioning query to create a crosstab/pivot table in Access

```
TRANSFORM Sum(y.TNAV) AS TNAV
SELECT y.RecDate
FROM BNYDaily AS y
WHERE (((y.AccName) In ("A","B")) AND y.RecDate >= DateValue("1/1/2013"))
GROUP BY y.RecDate
PIVOT y.AccName; )
```

The problem is that the query returns results with `NULL` fields that messes up my calculation. I want to omit rows in this crosstab table that have `NULL` value in either columns:

```
RecDate     A                   B
....
1/25/2013   1,469,004,032.00    968.63
1/26/2013   1,466,082,304.00    
1/28/2013                       973.91
1/29/2013   1,471,277,440.00    971.66
...
```

I tried the following query that uses the above query as a subquery without any luck:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
TRANSFORM Sum(y.TNAV) AS TNAV
SELECT y.RecDate
FROM BNYDaily AS y
WHERE (((y.AccName) In ("A","B")) AND y.RecDate >= DateValue("1/1/2013"))
GROUP BY y.RecDate
PIVOT y.AccName; 
) AS t
WHERE t.A IS NOT NULL AND t.B is NOT NULL
```

which oddly doesn't run in Access and returns an error. If I query from the crosstab query as a saved query table it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't just run your query against the saved crosstab query (since you already know that it works if you do it that way)? Crosstab queries behave a bit differently than other types of queries, and I've seen several other cases where crosstab queries don't work when we try to imbed their SQL as a subquery.

Comment: I process the data in Excel and have a VB script in Excel set up so I can alter `A` `B` based on user selection in a list. If I lock in a crosstab query table saved in Access then I lose this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "squeezing out" the rows containing Nulls from the *results* of the crosstab, how about eliminating the rows that produce the Nulls from the *source* of the crosstab? I just tried the following and it seems to work:

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(y.TNAV) AS TNAV
SELECT y.RecDate
FROM 
    (
        SELECT RecDate, AccName, TNAV
        FROM BNYDaily 
        WHERE RecDate IN (SELECT RecDate FROM BNYDaily WHERE AccName = "A")
            AND RecDate IN (SELECT RecDate FROM BNYDaily WHERE AccName = "B")
    ) AS y
WHERE (((y.AccName) In ("A","B")) AND y.RecDate >= DateValue("1/1/2013"))
GROUP BY y.RecDate
PIVOT y.AccName;
```

Comment: Thanks this actually works! I tried something similar in the beginning where I was trying to squeeze out the nulls in the `BNYDaily` table's values... but should have tried that on the dates!